# JS doesn´t recognize Freemarker variables

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker

I have this piece of code inside my Freemarker template:

```
<form>
  <#list elements as product>           
    <input id="${product.buyLink}" type="checkbox" onClick="addToCart()" /><#if product.title??>${product.title}</#if> - <#if product.price??>${package.price}<#else>missing price</#if><br />
    <script src="/assets/js/addToCart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </#list>
</form>
```

My addToCart.js looks like this:

```
function addToCart() {
   if (document.getElementById("${product.buyLink}").checked == true) {
        console.log("Product removed from cart.")
   } else {
        console.log("Product addded into cart.")
   }
}
```

When I run this code, Chrome dev tools keep showing this **error message**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
```

Also I think it is need to say that my variable `${product.buyLink}` is a string that contains many backlashes - for example it can look like this: `"db/45493/t/524s"`. I also tried to `console.log("${package.buyLink}");` at the top of my JS script and it returned `${package.buyLink}`.

So, tt seems like my JS script doesn't know `${product.buyLink}` at all or thinks it is equal to null. Where exactly is an error and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript runs on the **client**, FreeMarker runs on the **server**.
Here is an illustration:
[image]

As you can see there's the ***Internet*** separating your JavaScript code from `${product.buyLink}` which is something that's processed by FreeMarker on the **server**. You need to either move the code from *addToCart.js* inside the `<script>` tag of your FreeMarker template or create a new template from *addToCart.js* and process the template before you return it to the browser.

Just to make sure everything is clear your goal is to process `${product.buyLink}` on the **server** the JavaScript that runs in your browser must have `db/45493/t/524s` already in it, JavaScript runs in your browser and has no idea what `${product.buyLink}` is.